# how to change start year from date picker in materillize

Tags: css, materialize

I want to set start year from using materialize css and want to year start from 1990

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: is it working? if not than try to initialize latest version of materialize css

Comment: Yes it's working nicely and I'm using updated css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set range to datepicker

```
$(function(){
   $(".datepicker").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: '1990:'+(new Date).getFullYear() 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With Materialize version one

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      yearRange: 59
    });
```

Or alternatively, provide an array of the years you want... that can be easily done in Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      yearRange: [1970,2019]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify you javascript as given bellow to adjust year according you. I hope this will work for you.

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
  selectYears: 40 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
});
```